# PHP - WAMP Server - Test my HTACCESS ErrorPage (not working)

Tags: php, .htaccess, wamp

IN MY LOCAL (WAMP) SERVER:

I have this .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /views/oops.php
ErrorDocument 500 /views/oops.php
ErrorDocument 400 /views/oops.php
```

In my httpd.conf this line is Uncommented

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

The HTACCESS File is in the application root folder. When I visit this URL:

```
localhost/mywebapp/views/home.php
```

It works perfect, shows the home page. And if I enter something like

```
localhost/mywebapp/views/thisdoesnotexist  OR localhost/mywebapp/thisdoesnotexist
```

I want it to show me my error page, but it's showing the default and ugly error page.

Thank you beforehand.

EDIT: This is what it shows on error

```
Not Found

The requested URL /myapp/thisdoesnotexist was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Comment: have you restart your wamp server?

Comment: and localhost/mywebapp/views/oops.php do exist right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that the `oops.php` file is actually in the mywebapp folder, as opposed to the document root. The path that the `ErrorDocument` directive takes is an absolute URL, not relative to where the htaccess file is in. So you need to make sure the path points to the actual location of the error document:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /mywebapp/views/oops.php
ErrorDocument 500 /mywebapp/views/oops.php
ErrorDocument 400 /mywebapp/views/oops.php
```

Comment: Take this truck full of thanks! I didn't know that you must use Absolute paths with the HTACCESS. It's working now

Comment: @JuanBonnett you don't need to use absolute paths for everything in htaccess, but the `ErorDocument` directive must be absolute paths.